# How to reset the follow Meteor event every time it is triggered?

Tags: javascript, meteor

The following updates a `Document` collection on user `input` (with a tree-second delay):

```
Template.documentPage.events({
  'input .content': function(e) {
    // to make Tracker.autorun rerun
    Session.set('currentPostId',this._id)
    var currentPostId = Session.get('currentPostId')

    // to make setTimeout work
    Tracker.autorun(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        var savedSel = rangy.saveSelection()
        var content = $(e.target).html()

        Documents.update(currentPostId, {$set: {content: content}}, function(){
          rangy.restoreSelection(savedSel)
          console.log('saved')
        })
      }, 3000)
    })
  },
```

So now I'll see `2 saved` if I type two times `3` if I type 3 times and so on. How can I do it so that the events resets every time the user types? So that I end up only with `1 saved` (the last one)?

**EDIT:**

I tried this

```
Tracker.autorun(function(c) {
  c.stop()
  setTimeout(function() {
```

And this:

```
Tracker.autorun(function(c) {
  clearTimeout(timer)
  var timer = setTimeout(function() {
```

But didn't work.

Using Underscore's `_.debounce` didn't work either:

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
  _.debounce(function() {
    var savedSel = rangy.saveSelection()
    var content = $(e.target).html()

    Documents.update(currentPostId, {$set: {content: content}}, function(){
      rangy.restoreSelection(savedSel)
      console.log('saved')
    })
  }, 3000)
})
```

Comment: Can you try using _.debounce on the input event instead? For example: `'input .content': _.debounce(function(e) { ... }, 3000)`. I think you might just be re-running the _.debounce again every input change, rather than using the debounced version of the function.

Comment: @mark Hey, it worked. Why? Could you post an answer with a short explanation? I'll mark it up as the answer.

Comment: I added my answer. Hopefully the explanation makes sense (the hour is late...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is, you want to `_.debounce` the input event rather than the `Document.update` call:

```
Template.documentPage.events({
  'input .content': _.debounce(function(e) { ... }, 3000)
});
```

Explanation:

How underscore's `_.debounce` works is that it returns a function that wraps your original function. This new function returned by `_.debounce` regulates itself from running every time it is called, using some `setTimeouts` internally.

The key here is that `_.debounce` works by returning a special function -- `_.debounce` itself is just a regular function with no inherent time-regulating ability.

Having said this, let's go back to your example. Normally with `'input .content'`, every time the input changes, the input event is called again. This means that by putting your `_.debounce` function inside the event handler, all you are doing is calling `_.debounce` (the plain function, not the special returned function) again and again, throwing away the return value each time. In effect, the `Document.update` is never triggered, only used as a parameter to the `_.debounce` function that is promptly discarded.

If you instead wrap `_.debounce` around the event handler itself, the input event now triggers the special returned function on every input change, which is desired because this special function knows how to postpone execution of the original function (the parameter to the debounce function, which is your original event handler).

Comment: Isn't there a problem with the `currentPostId` ? If you debounce the whole `input .content` event and change `currentPostId`bettween 2 debounces, doesn't it use the last `currentPostId` when the function actually runs ?

Comment: No, `_.debounce` does not change the context so `this.id` will still be referring to a dynamic `this` context.

Comment: https://github.com/darkship/test_debounce I tried and it fails. `this`   refer to the last template instance's data. This means

Comment: the updated document would be wrong if you change `currentPostId` before the 3000ms

Comment: Your example works as expected for me; it alerts the `_id` of the correct document when I change inputs before 3000ms are up. This is because `debounce` doesn't actually run the event handler function until after 3s of 'inactivity'. When it *does* run the function, the `this` context will be referring to the document currently bound to the input that last triggered the 'input' event -- thus the update will occur to the element that you intend to update.

Answer (score 2):

You could use http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

```
_.debounce(function(){
    Documents.update(currentPostId, {$set: {content: content}}, function(){
      rangy.restoreSelection(savedSel)
      console.log('saved')
    })
}, 3000)
```

Comment: Please see my **EDIT**. Now with `_.debounce` nothing happens. The document isn't being saved.